# Checking whether Gridview contains specific Bind property or not

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, aspxgridview, itemtemplate

I've been working on ASPX webform application where i have a gridview having text box control. My problem is, i want to set Text value for this textbox only when it have Bind Property.

```
<asp:GridView ID="grvShowRecord" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Value">
        <ItemTemplate> 
            -- Something like this, i don't know how to write in ASPX, but in Razor it will be something like
            @{
                if(Bind("txtValue")!=null) -- IF gridview has Bind("txtValue") property then show textbox else show label 
                {
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtValue" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("txtValue") %>' ></asp:TextBox>    
                }
                else
                {
                    <asp:Label ID="lblValue" runat="server" Text="0" ></asp:TextBox>
                }
            }                           
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

NOTE: Initially when Binding Gridview on Page Load, i'm not using any Bind property but later i'm setting this Bind property and then binding gridview again.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Value">
    <ItemTemplate> 
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtValue" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("txtValue") %>' Visible='<%# !IsNullValue("txtValue") %>' />
        <asp:Label ID="lblValue" runat="server" Text="0" Visible='<%# IsNullValue("txtValue") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

with this utility function defined in code-behind:

```
protected bool IsNullValue(string fieldName)
{
    try
    {
        object value = Eval(fieldName);
        return Convert.IsDBNull(value) || value == null || value.ToString() == string.Empty;
    }
    catch
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting exception "DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'txtValue'".

Comment: As i told above when i'm first loading gridview, i'm not setting any Bind property, and this Bind property is manually added from Code Behind file

Comment: I modified my answer to take into account the fact that the field may not always exist.